# enable/disable select if radio checked

Tags: jquery, html

In my HTML i want to check the state for my radio buttons, to see if they are enabled or disabled. I have this HTML structure:

```
 <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:20px;">
                                <input type="radio" id="rdoLevel" name="rdoSelect"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>ارسال براساس مقطع : </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypeLevel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="False">
                                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>ابتدایی</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>راهنمایی</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>دبیرستان</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>پیش دانشگاهی</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>دانشگاه</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" id="rdoBase" name="rdoSelect"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>ارسال براساس پایه :</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypeBase" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  Enabled="False">
                                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>اول</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>دوم</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>سوم</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" id="rdoSchool" name="rdoSelect" />
                            </td>
                            <td>ارسال براساس مدرسه :</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSchooNameType" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" id="rdoTypeRegistre" name="rdoSelect"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>ارسال براساس نوع ثبت نام :</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypeRegister" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                                    Enabled="False">
                                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>ثبت نام</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>پیش ثبت نام</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSendByCategory" Enabled="false" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-small rtl"
                                    Text="ارسال" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

And i use this jquery code for check the states :

```
$("input:radio").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var ddlTypeLevel = $("#ddlTypeLevel");
    if (id == "rdoLevel") {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('select#ddlTypeLevel').prop('disabled', false);
        } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
            $('select#ddlTypeLevel').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }
    else if (id == "rdoBase") {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('select#ddlTypeBase').prop('disabled', false);
        } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
            $('select#ddlTypeBase').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }
    else if (id == "rdoSchool") {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#txtSchooNameType').prop('disabled', false);
        } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
            $('#txtSchooNameType').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }
    else if (id == "rdoTypeRegistre") {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('select#ddlTypeRegister').prop('disabled', false);
        } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
            $('select#ddlTypeRegister').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }
});
```

But the above code does not work. Only the enable check works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`not` doesn't return a boolean value, you can use negation operator instead:

```
} else if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
```

Also when a radio is not checked it's unchecked so there is no need to check the state again.

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
    var id = this.id.replace('rdo', ''); 
    $('#ddlType'+id).prop('disabled', !this.checked);     
});
```

Based on your current logic you can minify your code. note that `:radio` selector is deprecated.

Comment: can you put your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Okay, jsfiddle doesn't render serverside codes, please create a fiddle with your rendered markup and I'll update it.

Comment: Or this http://jsfiddle.net/Bn3aJ/

Comment: yes ,thanks,secode one works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr` instead of `prop` to disable the elements.

Also, you could disable all the elements at the beginnning of the function and after that only enable the one that corresponds to the selected radio button.

Your code could look like this:

```
$("input:radio").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    $('select').attr('disabled', 'true');

    if (id == "rdoLevel") {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('select#ddlTypeLevel').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }
    else if (id == "rdoBase") {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('select#ddlTypeBase').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }
    else if (id == "rdoSchool") {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#txtSchooNameType').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }
    else if (id == "rdoTypeRegistre") {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('select#ddlTypeRegister').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }
});​
```

**Here's a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/bujkw/2/**

---

Also, another thing I noticed: instead of your `if(enabled){}else if(not enabled){}` approach, you could simply do `if(enabled){}else{}`.

Concretely, instead of

```
if (id == "rdoLevel") {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('select#ddlTypeLevel').prop('disabled', false);
    } else if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
        $('select#ddlTypeLevel').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

you could simply write

```
if (id == "rdoLevel") {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('select#ddlTypeLevel').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('select#ddlTypeLevel').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

This way the code is a bit more simple and it avoids the issue of using [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) incorrectly, as pointed out by undefined in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13173058/390819).

Comment: it's not working for me.

Comment: it's just enable ddlTypeLevel and ddlTypeLevel.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi are you using the code that's also in the jsFiddle example? If so, check the client ids of the select elements and that selectors like `$('select#ddlTypeBase')` work

Comment: it's work in jsFiddle but it's not work for me,it just enable $('select#ddlTypeLevel') and $('select#ddlTypeRegister').

Comment: @SirwanAfifi try the `$('select#ddlTypeBase')` and `$('#txtSchooNameType')` selectors on your web page. Do they work?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi OK, I know what this last problem is: `rdoBase` and `rdoSchool` need to have `ClientIDMode="Static"` in you ASP page.